# document.getElementById doesn't retrieve an element that actually exists

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Here is the DOM that clearly contains an input with id=`RESULT_TextField-11`:
[image]

But when I try to retrieve it from Chrome console using document.getElementById method, it doesn't work:

[image]

document.getElementsByName doesn't work either.

**Why could this happen?** The first screenshot was taken before the second one.

What's interesting is that when I try to run the same code in console a few minutes later, it often works.

Some information that may help:

- I'm using the latest Chrome on Windows 7.
- The form that contains `RESULT_TextField-11` input was created using formsite.com
- Here is the page where the problem occurs: https://www.creativebrands.co.za/contact-creative-brands/

Comment: vague possibility: because it's line-broken in the debugger, make sure there isn't a space in there, e.g. `RESULT_TextField-[space]11`

Comment: it's in his console.

Comment: That's a wordpress site that loads dynamic content ?

Comment: It's because the input is in an iframe.

Comment: @adeneo Yes. A <script> element is embedded from an external domain (formsite.com), and this script creates the form (including the mentioned input).

Comment: @HenrikRipa brilliant! Thanks. Want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input can't be found because it's within an iFrame. You would have to target it with something like this instead:

```
document.getElementById('frame-one997541297').contentWindow.document.getElementById('RESULT_TextField-11')
```

However, that won't work either because the iFrame is loaded from another domain. So scripts at your site won't be able to interact with content from the iFrame's site due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).